# Tangent to curve interpolated from discrete data

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation

I was wondering if there's a way to find tangents to curve from discrete data.
For example:

```
x = np.linespace(-100,100,100001)
y = sin(x)
```

so here x values are integers, but what if we want to find tangent at something like `x = 67.875`?

I've been trying to figure out if `numpy.interp` would work, but so far no luck.
I also found a couple of similar examples, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391449/find-tangent-vector-at-a-point-for-discrete-data-points), but haven't been able to apply the techniques to my case :(
I'm new to Python and don't entirely know how everything works yet, so any help would be appreciated...

this is what I get: [image]

```
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-100,100,10000)
y = np.sin(x)
tck, u = interpolate.splprep([y])

ti = np.linspace(-100,100,10000)
dydx = interpolate.splev(ti,tck,der=1)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(ti,dydx[0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13419640/4124317) from the link you have directly shows you the solution, does it not? So please do not ask a question which would get the same answer. Instead show us in how far you cannot apply this method or what goes wrong if you attempt to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13419640/4124317), which tells you that there is a difference between `splrep` and `splprep`.  For the 1D case you have here, `splrep` is completely sufficient.

You may also want to limit your curve a but to be able to see the oscilations.

```
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-15,15,1000)
y = np.sin(x)
tck = interpolate.splrep(x,y)

dydx = interpolate.splev(x,tck,der=1)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,dydx, label="derivative")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

While this is how the code above would be made runnable, it does not provide a tangent. For the tangent you only need the derivative at a single point. However you need to have the equation of a tangent somewhere and actually *use* it; so this is more a math question.

```
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-15,15,1000)
y = np.sin(x)
tck = interpolate.splrep(x,y)

x0 = 7.3
y0 = interpolate.splev(x0,tck)
dydx = interpolate.splev(x0,tck,der=1)

tngnt = lambda x: dydx*x + (y0-dydx*x0)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x0,y0, "or")
plt.plot(x,tngnt(x), label="tangent")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

It should be noted that you do not need to use splines at all if the points you have are dense enough. In that case obtaining the derivative is just taking the differences between the nearest points.

```
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-15,15,1000)
y = np.sin(x)

x0 = 7.3
i0 = np.argmin(np.abs(x-x0))
x1 = x[i0:i0+2]
y1 = y[i0:i0+2]
dydx, = np.diff(y1)/np.diff(x1)

tngnt = lambda x: dydx*x + (y1[0]-dydx*x1[0])

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x1[0],y1[0], "or")
plt.plot(x,tngnt(x), label="tangent")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The result will be visually identical to the one above.

Comment: Yay! What an excellent answer. Thanks so much. I was just reading up on what B-spline representation (or spline even...) is because I've never even heard the term %\ and it's kinda hard figuring out what the function does when I don't even understand the basic concept...
This is very helpful though as I can follow it through with knowing what the outcome should be.
Cheers.

Comment: You do not actually need splines. I updated the answer to show how it would be done the standard way.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing it something like that, but isn't B-spline more accurate since there's not really a straight line between points?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the difference. The question is just, how accurate do you need the result to be?

Comment: Couldn't you also slowly modulate the slope of the tangent between the two known slopes at two data points depending on how close the input point is to one or the other?

Comment: Yes, those are all concepts of [numerical differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Higher-order_methods).