# Tangent along graph profile Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to figure out a way to draw a tangent on my graph profile. I am reading my x and y points from a text file. [image: Profile]

```
0.000847190000 0.000350000000
0.000847190000 0.000350000000
0.000847200000 0.000346020000
0.000847200000 0.000346020000
0.000847240000 0.000342050000
0.000847240000 0.000342050000
0.000847300000 0.000338070000
0.000847300000 0.000338070000
0.000847400000 0.000334090000
0.000847400000 0.000334090000
0.000847520000 0.000330110000
0.000847520000 0.000330110000
0.000847670000 0.000326140000
0.000847670000 0.000326140000
0.000847860000 0.000322160000
0.000847860000 0.000322160000
0.000848000000 0.000319750000
0.000848000000 0.000319750000
0.000848090000 0.000318180000
0.000848090000 0.000318180000
0.000848340000 0.000314200000
0.000848340000 0.000314200000
0.000848610000 0.000310230000
0.000848610000 0.000310230000
0.000848890000 0.000306250000
0.000848890000 0.000306250000
0.000849190000 0.000302270000
0.000849190000 0.000302270000
0.000849510000 0.000298300000
0.000849510000 0.000298300000
0.000849860000 0.000294320000
0.000849860000 0.000294320000
0.000850220000 0.000290340000
0.000850220000 0.000290340000
0.000850610000 0.000286360000
0.000850610000 0.000286360000
0.000851040000 0.000282390000
0.000851040000 0.000282390000
0.000851530000 0.000278410000
0.000851530000 0.000278410000
0.000852000000 0.000275160000
0.000852000000 0.000275160000
0.000852110000 0.000274430000
0.000852110000 0.000274430000
0.000852690000 0.000270450000
0.000852690000 0.000270450000
0.000853240000 0.000266480000
0.000853240000 0.000266480000
0.000853780000 0.000262500000
0.000853780000 0.000262500000
0.000854330000 0.000258520000
0.000854330000 0.000258520000
0.000854940000 0.000254550000
0.000854940000 0.000254550000
0.000855620000 0.000250570000
0.000855620000 0.000250570000
0.000856000000 0.000248680000
0.000856000000 0.000248680000
0.000856420000 0.000246590000
0.000856420000 0.000246590000
0.000857150000 0.000242610000
0.000857150000 0.000242610000
0.000857860000 0.000238640000
0.000857860000 0.000238640000
0.000858580000 0.000234660000
0.000858580000 0.000234660000
0.000859390000 0.000230680000
0.000859390000 0.000230680000
0.000860000000 0.000228110000
0.000860000000 0.000228110000
0.000860350000 0.000226700000
0.000860350000 0.000226700000
0.000861240000 0.000222730000
0.000861240000 0.000222730000
0.000862080000 0.000218750000
0.000862080000 0.000218750000
0.000862980000 0.000214770000
0.000862980000 0.000214770000
0.000864000000 0.000210910000
0.000864000000 0.000210910000
0.000864030000 0.000210800000
0.000864030000 0.000210800000
0.000865110000 0.000206820000
0.000865110000 0.000206820000
0.000866080000 0.000202840000
0.000866080000 0.000202840000
0.000867110000 0.000198860000
0.000867110000 0.000198860000
0.000868000000 0.000195990000
0.000868000000 0.000195990000
0.000868360000 0.000194890000
0.000868360000 0.000194890000
0.000869510000 0.000190910000
0.000869510000 0.000190910000
0.000870630000 0.000186930000
0.000870630000 0.000186930000
0.000871920000 0.000182950000
0.000871920000 0.000182950000
0.000872000000 0.000182730000
0.000872000000 0.000182730000
0.000873270000 0.000178980000
0.000873270000 0.000178980000
0.000874500000 0.000175000000
0.000874500000 0.000175000000
0.000875910000 0.000171020000
0.000875910000 0.000171020000
0.000876000000 0.000170820000
0.000876000000 0.000170820000
0.000877400000 0.000167050000
0.000877400000 0.000167050000
0.000878760000 0.000163070000
0.000878760000 0.000163070000
0.000880000000 0.000160030000
0.000880000000 0.000160030000
0.000880410000 0.000159090000
0.000880410000 0.000159090000
0.000881930000 0.000155110000
0.000881930000 0.000155110000
0.000883520000 0.000151140000
0.000883520000 0.000151140000
0.000884000000 0.000150130000
0.000884000000 0.000150130000
0.000885320000 0.000147160000
0.000885320000 0.000147160000
0.000886970000 0.000143180000
0.000886970000 0.000143180000
0.000888000000 0.000141090000
0.000888000000 0.000141090000
0.000888930000 0.000139200000
0.000888930000 0.000139200000
0.000890710000 0.000135230000
0.000890710000 0.000135230000
0.000892000000 0.000132750000
0.000892000000 0.000132750000
0.000892810000 0.000131250000
0.000892810000 0.000131250000
0.000894730000 0.000127270000
0.000894730000 0.000127270000
0.000896000000 0.000125000000
0.000896000000 0.000125000000
0.000896970000 0.000123300000
0.000896970000 0.000123300000
0.000899050000 0.000119320000
0.000899050000 0.000119320000
0.000900000000 0.000117760000
0.000900000000 0.000117760000
0.000901450000 0.000115340000
0.000901450000 0.000115340000
0.000903740000 0.000111360000
0.000903740000 0.000111360000
0.000904000000 0.000110980000
0.000904000000 0.000110980000
0.000906230000 0.000107390000
0.000906230000 0.000107390000
0.000908000000 0.000104690000
0.000908000000 0.000104690000
0.000908890000 0.000103410000
0.000908890000 0.000103410000
0.000911420000 0.000099432000
0.000911420000 0.000099432000
0.000912000000 0.000098650000
0.000912000000 0.000098650000
0.000914240000 0.000095455000
0.000914240000 0.000095455000
0.000916000000 0.000093056000
0.000916000000 0.000093056000
0.000917200000 0.000091477000
0.000917200000 0.000091477000
0.000920000000 0.000087664000
0.000920000000 0.000087664000
0.000920130000 0.000087500000
0.000920130000 0.000087500000
0.000923130000 0.000083523000
0.000923130000 0.000083523000
0.000924000000 0.000082494000
0.000924000000 0.000082494000
0.000926390000 0.000079545000
0.000926390000 0.000079545000
0.000928000000 0.000077654000
0.000928000000 0.000077654000
0.000929790000 0.000075568000
0.000929790000 0.000075568000
0.000932000000 0.000073014000
0.000932000000 0.000073014000
0.000933280000 0.000071591000
0.000933280000 0.000071591000
0.000936000000 0.000068532000
0.000936000000 0.000068532000
0.000936860000 0.000067614000
0.000936860000 0.000067614000
0.000940000000 0.000064213000
0.000940000000 0.000064213000
0.000940560000 0.000063636000
0.000940560000 0.000063636000
0.000944000000 0.000060085000
0.000944000000 0.000060085000
0.000944430000 0.000059659000
0.000944430000 0.000059659000
0.000948000000 0.000056177000
0.000948000000 0.000056177000
0.000948520000 0.000055682000
0.000948520000 0.000055682000
0.000952000000 0.000052495000
0.000952000000 0.000052495000
0.000952870000 0.000051705000
0.000952870000 0.000051705000
0.000956000000 0.000049012000
0.000956000000 0.000049012000
0.000957520000 0.000047727000
0.000957520000 0.000047727000
0.000960000000 0.000045705000
0.000960000000 0.000045705000
0.000962560000 0.000043750000
0.000962560000 0.000043750000
0.000964000000 0.000042634000
0.000964000000 0.000042634000
0.000968000000 0.000039979000
0.000968000000 0.000039979000
0.000968290000 0.000039773000
0.000968290000 0.000039773000
0.000972000000 0.000037449000
0.000972000000 0.000037449000
0.000974790000 0.000035795000
0.000974790000 0.000035795000
0.000976000000 0.000035046000
0.000976000000 0.000035046000
0.000980000000 0.000033052000
0.000980000000 0.000033052000
0.000982440000 0.000031818000
0.000982440000 0.000031818000
0.000984000000 0.000031017000
0.000984000000 0.000031017000
0.000988000000 0.000029347000
0.000988000000 0.000029347000
0.000991650000 0.000027841000
0.000991650000 0.000027841000
0.000992000000 0.000027684000
0.000992000000 0.000027684000
0.000996000000 0.000026225000
0.000996000000 0.000026225000
0.001000000000 0.000024939000
0.001000000000 0.000024939000
0.001003400000 0.000023864000
0.001003400000 0.000023864000
0.001004000000 0.000023681000
0.001004000000 0.000023681000
0.001008000000 0.000022556000
0.001008000000 0.000022556000
0.001012000000 0.000021554000
0.001012000000 0.000021554000
0.001016000000 0.000020696000
0.001016000000 0.000020696000
0.001020000000 0.000019943000
0.001020000000 0.000019943000
0.001020300000 0.000019886000
0.001020300000 0.000019886000
0.001024000000 0.000019248000
0.001024000000 0.000019248000
0.001028000000 0.000018598000
0.001028000000 0.000018598000
0.001032000000 0.000017944000
0.001032000000 0.000017944000
0.001036000000 0.000017304000
0.001036000000 0.000017304000
0.001040000000 0.000016703000
0.001040000000 0.000016703000
0.001044000000 0.000016150000
0.001044000000 0.000016150000
0.001045900000 0.000015909000
0.001045900000 0.000015909000
0.001048000000 0.000015655000
0.001048000000 0.000015655000
0.001052000000 0.000015257000
0.001052000000 0.000015257000
0.001056000000 0.000014915000
0.001056000000 0.000014915000
0.001060000000 0.000014605000
0.001060000000 0.000014605000
0.001064000000 0.000014313000
0.001064000000 0.000014313000
0.001068000000 0.000014032000
0.001068000000 0.000014032000
0.001072000000 0.000013761000
0.001072000000 0.000013761000
0.001076000000 0.000013499000
0.001076000000 0.000013499000
0.001080000000 0.000013248000
0.001080000000 0.000013248000
0.001084000000 0.000013009000
0.001084000000 0.000013009000
0.001088000000 0.000012782000
0.001088000000 0.000012782000
0.001092000000 0.000012564000
0.001092000000 0.000012564000
0.001096000000 0.000012356000
0.001096000000 0.000012356000
0.001100000000 0.000012156000
0.001100000000 0.000012156000
0.001104000000 0.000011962000
0.001104000000 0.000011962000
0.001104600000 0.000011932000
0.001104600000 0.000011932000
0.001108000000 0.000011780000
0.001108000000 0.000011780000
0.001112000000 0.000011615000
0.001112000000 0.000011615000
0.001116000000 0.000011464000
0.001116000000 0.000011464000
0.001120000000 0.000011325000
0.001120000000 0.000011325000
0.001124000000 0.000011195000
0.001124000000 0.000011195000
0.001128000000 0.000011074000
0.001128000000 0.000011074000
0.001132000000 0.000010959000
0.001132000000 0.000010959000
0.001136000000 0.000010851000
0.001136000000 0.000010851000
0.001140000000 0.000010749000
0.001140000000 0.000010749000
0.001144000000 0.000010651000
0.001144000000 0.000010651000
0.001148000000 0.000010558000
0.001148000000 0.000010558000
0.001152000000 0.000010469000
0.001152000000 0.000010469000
0.001156000000 0.000010383000
0.001156000000 0.000010383000
0.001160000000 0.000010301000
0.001160000000 0.000010301000
0.001164000000 0.000010222000
0.001164000000 0.000010222000
0.001168000000 0.000010145000
0.001168000000 0.000010145000
0.001172000000 0.000010072000
0.001172000000 0.000010072000
0.001176000000 0.000010000000
0.001176000000 0.000010000000
0.001180000000 0.000009931200
0.001180000000 0.000009931200
0.001184000000 0.000009864200
0.001184000000 0.000009864200
0.001188000000 0.000009799200
0.001188000000 0.000009799200
0.001192000000 0.000009736100
0.001192000000 0.000009736100
0.001196000000 0.000009674700
0.001196000000 0.000009674700
0.001200000000 0.000009615000
0.001200000000 0.000009615000
0.001204000000 0.000009556800
0.001204000000 0.000009556800
0.001208000000 0.000009500000
0.001208000000 0.000009500000
0.001212000000 0.000009444700
0.001212000000 0.000009444700
0.001216000000 0.000009390600
0.001216000000 0.000009390600
0.001220000000 0.000009337800
0.001220000000 0.000009337800
0.001224000000 0.000009286200
0.001224000000 0.000009286200
0.001228000000 0.000009235800
0.001228000000 0.000009235800
0.001232000000 0.000009186500
0.001232000000 0.000009186500
0.001236000000 0.000009138200
0.001236000000 0.000009138200
0.001240000000 0.000009090900
0.001240000000 0.000009090900
0.001244000000 0.000009044400
0.001244000000 0.000009044400
0.001248000000 0.000008998600
0.001248000000 0.000008998600
0.001252000000 0.000008953600
0.001252000000 0.000008953600
0.001256000000 0.000008909300
0.001256000000 0.000008909300
0.001260000000 0.000008865700
0.001260000000 0.000008865700
0.001264000000 0.000008823000
0.001264000000 0.000008823000
0.001268000000 0.000008781100
0.001268000000 0.000008781100
0.001272000000 0.000008740200
0.001272000000 0.000008740200
0.001276000000 0.000008700200
0.001276000000 0.000008700200
0.001280000000 0.000008660900
0.001280000000 0.000008660900
0.001284000000 0.000008622200
0.001284000000 0.000008622200
0.001288000000 0.000008583900
0.001288000000 0.000008583900
0.001292000000 0.000008545700
0.001292000000 0.000008545700
0.001296000000 0.000008507500
0.001296000000 0.000008507500
0.001300000000 0.000008469200
0.001300000000 0.000008469200
0.001304000000 0.000008431000
0.001304000000 0.000008431000
0.001308000000 0.000008393100
0.001308000000 0.000008393100
0.001312000000 0.000008355800
0.001312000000 0.000008355800
0.001316000000 0.000008319200
0.001316000000 0.000008319200
0.001320000000 0.000008283700
0.001320000000 0.000008283700
0.001324000000 0.000008249000
0.001324000000 0.000008249000
0.001328000000 0.000008215000
0.001328000000 0.000008215000
0.001332000000 0.000008181300
0.001332000000 0.000008181300
0.001336000000 0.000008147800
0.001336000000 0.000008147800
0.001340000000 0.000008114100
0.001340000000 0.000008114100
0.001344000000 0.000008080400
0.001344000000 0.000008080400
0.001348000000 0.000008046700
0.001348000000 0.000008046700
0.001352000000 0.000008013200
0.001352000000 0.000008013200
0.001356000000 0.000007980200
0.001356000000 0.000007980200
0.001359200000 0.000007954500
0.001359200000 0.000007954500
0.001360000000 0.000007948100
0.001360000000 0.000007948100
0.001364000000 0.000007917400
0.001364000000 0.000007917400
0.001368000000 0.000007887900
0.001368000000 0.000007887900
0.001372000000 0.000007859300
0.001372000000 0.000007859300
0.001376000000 0.000007831200
0.001376000000 0.000007831200
0.001380000000 0.000007803400
0.001380000000 0.000007803400
0.001384000000 0.000007775600
0.001384000000 0.000007775600
0.001388000000 0.000007747800
0.001388000000 0.000007747800
0.001392000000 0.000007720100
0.001392000000 0.000007720100
0.001396000000 0.000007692700
0.001396000000 0.000007692700
0.001400000000 0.000007666100
0.001400000000 0.000007666100
0.001404000000 0.000007640500
0.001404000000 0.000007640500
0.001408000000 0.000007616200
0.001408000000 0.000007616200
0.001412000000 0.000007593400
0.001412000000 0.000007593400
0.001416000000 0.000007571800
0.001416000000 0.000007571800
0.001420000000 0.000007551100
0.001420000000 0.000007551100
0.001424000000 0.000007530900
0.001424000000 0.000007530900
0.001428000000 0.000007510800
0.001428000000 0.000007510800
0.001432000000 0.000007490400
0.001432000000 0.000007490400
0.001436000000 0.000007469600
0.001436000000 0.000007469600
0.001440000000 0.000007448200
0.001440000000 0.000007448200
0.001444000000 0.000007426400
0.001444000000 0.000007426400
0.001448000000 0.000007404400
0.001448000000 0.000007404400
0.001452000000 0.000007382500
0.001452000000 0.000007382500
0.001456000000 0.000007361100
0.001456000000 0.000007361100
0.001460000000 0.000007340300
0.001460000000 0.000007340300
0.001464000000 0.000007320600
0.001464000000 0.000007320600
0.001468000000 0.000007302000
0.001468000000 0.000007302000
0.001472000000 0.000007284700
0.001472000000 0.000007284700
0.001476000000 0.000007268400
0.001476000000 0.000007268400
0.001480000000 0.000007252900
0.001480000000 0.000007252900
0.001484000000 0.000007237900
0.001484000000 0.000007237900
0.001488000000 0.000007223000
0.001488000000 0.000007223000
0.001492000000 0.000007207600
0.001492000000 0.000007207600
0.001496000000 0.000007191500
0.001496000000 0.000007191500
0.001500000000 0.000007174800
0.001500000000 0.000007174800
0.001504000000 0.000007157500
0.001504000000 0.000007157500
0.001508000000 0.000007139800
0.001508000000 0.000007139800
0.001512000000 0.000007121900
0.001512000000 0.000007121900
0.001516000000 0.000007104100
0.001516000000 0.000007104100
0.001520000000 0.000007086700
0.001520000000 0.000007086700
0.001524000000 0.000007070300
0.001524000000 0.000007070300
0.001528000000 0.000007055700
0.001528000000 0.000007055700
0.001532000000 0.000007042600
0.001532000000 0.000007042600
0.001536000000 0.000007030100
0.001536000000 0.000007030100
0.001540000000 0.000007017100
0.001540000000 0.000007017100
0.001544000000 0.000007004000
0.001544000000 0.000007004000
0.001548000000 0.000006992300
0.001548000000 0.000006992300
0.001552000000 0.000006982500
0.001552000000 0.000006982500
0.001556000000 0.000006973900
0.001556000000 0.000006973900
0.001560000000 0.000006965000
0.001560000000 0.000006965000
0.001564000000 0.000006954800
0.001564000000 0.000006954800
0.001568000000 0.000006941200
0.001568000000 0.000006941200
0.001572000000 0.000006922200
0.001572000000 0.000006922200
0.001576000000 0.000006901800
0.001576000000 0.000006901800
0.001580000000 0.000006888000
0.001580000000 0.000006888000
0.001584000000 0.000006878400
0.001584000000 0.000006878400
0.001588000000 0.000006857700
0.001588000000 0.000006857700
0.001592000000 0.000006815700
0.001592000000 0.000006815700
0.001596000000 0.000006775700
0.001596000000 0.000006775700
0.001600000000 0.000006764300
0.001600000000 0.000006764300
0.001604000000 0.000006774300
0.001604000000 0.000006774300
0.001608000000 0.000006796300
0.001608000000 0.000006796300
0.001612000000 0.000006817700
0.001612000000 0.000006817700
0.001616000000 0.000006823200
0.001616000000 0.000006823200
0.001620000000 0.000006815500
0.001620000000 0.000006815500
0.001624000000 0.000006802400
0.001624000000 0.000006802400
0.001628000000 0.000006787300
0.001628000000 0.000006787300
0.001632000000 0.000006771800
0.001632000000 0.000006771800
0.001636000000 0.000006758300
0.001636000000 0.000006758300
0.001640000000 0.000006752100
0.001640000000 0.000006752100
0.001644000000 0.000006747500
0.001644000000 0.000006747500
0.001648000000 0.000006726700
0.001648000000 0.000006726700
0.001652000000 0.000006676300
0.001652000000 0.000006676300
0.001656000000 0.000006627600
0.001656000000 0.000006627600
0.001660000000 0.000006617300
0.001660000000 0.000006617300
0.001664000000 0.000006641400
0.001664000000 0.000006641400
0.001668000000 0.000006680300
0.001668000000 0.000006680300
0.001672000000 0.000006692800
0.001672000000 0.000006692800
0.001676000000 0.000006653800
0.001676000000 0.000006653800
0.001680000000 0.000006552800
0.001680000000 0.000006552800
0.001684000000 0.000006418900
0.001684000000 0.000006418900
0.001688000000 0.000006352000
0.001688000000 0.000006352000
0.001692000000 0.000006380800
0.001692000000 0.000006380800
0.001696000000 0.000006499000
0.001696000000 0.000006499000
0.001700000000 0.000006691000
0.001700000000 0.000006691000
0.001704000000 0.000006824100
0.001704000000 0.000006824100
0.001708000000 0.000006846900
0.001708000000 0.000006846900
0.001712000000 0.000006821900
0.001712000000 0.000006821900
0.001716000000 0.000006740500
0.001716000000 0.000006740500
0.001720000000 0.000006580100
0.001720000000 0.000006580100
0.001724000000 0.000006452300
0.001724000000 0.000006452300
0.001728000000 0.000006451000
0.001728000000 0.000006451000
0.001732000000 0.000006564300
0.001732000000 0.000006564300
0.001736000000 0.000006715200
0.001736000000 0.000006715200
0.001740000000 0.000006730500
0.001740000000 0.000006730500
0.001744000000 0.000006403600
0.001744000000 0.000006403600
0.001748000000 0.000005671700
0.001748000000 0.000005671700
0.001752000000 0.000005218800
0.001752000000 0.000005218800
0.001756000000 0.000005580600
0.001756000000 0.000005580600
0.001760000000 0.000006507700
0.001760000000 0.000006507700
0.001764000000 0.000007275000
0.001764000000 0.000007275000
0.001768000000 0.000007451900
0.001768000000 0.000007451900
0.001772000000 0.000007259100
0.001772000000 0.000007259100
0.001776000000 0.000006712000
0.001776000000 0.000006712000
0.001780000000 0.000006201400
0.001780000000 0.000006201400
0.001784000000 0.000006203400
0.001784000000 0.000006203400
0.001788000000 0.000006608400
0.001788000000 0.000006608400
0.001792000000 0.000006964700
0.001792000000 0.000006964700
0.001796000000 0.000006881600
0.001796000000 0.000006881600
0.001800000000 0.000006057200
0.001800000000 0.000006057200
0.001804000000 0.000004858300
0.001804000000 0.000004858300
0.001808000000 0.000004510900
0.001808000000 0.000004510900
0.001812000000 0.000005355300
0.001812000000 0.000005355300
0.001816000000 0.000006635500
0.001816000000 0.000006635500
0.001820000000 0.000007306600
0.001820000000 0.000007306600
0.001824000000 0.000007265800
0.001824000000 0.000007265800
0.001828000000 0.000007022700
0.001828000000 0.000007022700
0.001832000000 0.000006895700
0.001832000000 0.000006895700
0.001836000000 0.000006981700
0.001836000000 0.000006981700
0.001840000000 0.000006961300
0.001840000000 0.000006961300
0.001844000000 0.000006289200
0.001844000000 0.000006289200
0.001848000000 0.000004530800
0.001848000000 0.000004530800
0.001849600000 0.000003977300
0.001849600000 0.000003977300
0.001852000000 0.000002990900
0.001852000000 0.000002990900
0.001856000000 0.000003571600
0.001856000000 0.000003571600
0.001856700000 0.000003977300
0.001856700000 0.000003977300
0.001860000000 0.000005475400
0.001860000000 0.000005475400
0.001864000000 0.000007292100
0.001864000000 0.000007292100
0.001867300000 0.000007954500
0.001867300000 0.000007954500
0.001868000000 0.000008098700
0.001868000000 0.000008098700
0.001872000000 0.000008285800
0.001872000000 0.000008285800
0.001876000000 0.000008181200
0.001876000000 0.000008181200
0.001877900000 0.000007954500
0.001877900000 0.000007954500
0.001880000000 0.000007685700
0.001880000000 0.000007685700
0.001884000000 0.000007300600
0.001884000000 0.000007300600
0.001888000000 0.000007087900
0.001888000000 0.000007087900
0.001892000000 0.000006607500
0.001892000000 0.000006607500
0.001896000000 0.000005413200
0.001896000000 0.000005413200
0.001898500000 0.000003977300
0.001898500000 0.000003977300
0.001900000000 0.000002442600
0.001900000000 0.000002442600
0.001901600000 0.000000000000
0.001919000000 0.000000000000
0.001919400000 0.000003977300
0.001919400000 0.000003977300
0.001920000000 0.000004797100
0.001920000000 0.000004797100
0.001923600000 0.000007954500
0.001923600000 0.000007954500
0.001924000000 0.000008148200
0.001924000000 0.000008148200
0.001928000000 0.000009562200
0.001928000000 0.000009562200
0.001932000000 0.000010575000
0.001932000000 0.000010575000
0.001936000000 0.000010740000
0.001936000000 0.000010740000
0.001940000000 0.000009914300
0.001940000000 0.000009914300
0.001943800000 0.000007954500
0.001943800000 0.000007954500
0.001944000000 0.000007841100
0.001944000000 0.000007841100
0.001948000000 0.000004630400
0.001948000000 0.000004630400
0.001948700000 0.000003977300
0.001948700000 0.000003977300
0.001950800000 0.000000000000
0.001975700000 0.000000000000
0.001976000000 0.000000786780
0.001976000000 0.000000786780
0.001977000000 0.000003977300
0.001977000000 0.000003977300
0.001980000000 0.000007153700
0.001980000000 0.000007153700
0.001981000000 0.000007954500
0.001981000000 0.000007954500
0.001984000000 0.000009824900
0.001984000000 0.000009824900
0.001988000000 0.000010981000
0.001988000000 0.000010981000
0.001992000000 0.000010765000
0.001992000000 0.000010765000
0.001996000000 0.000009199000
0.001996000000 0.000009199000
0.001997600000 0.000007954500
0.001997600000 0.000007954500
0.002000000000 0.000004683500
0.002000000000 0.000004683500
```

I want to include a tangent line along the curve to analyse where the tangent line cuts the x-axis. I read the answer from [Tangent to curve interpolated from discrete data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635428/tangent-to-curve-interpolated-from-discrete-data) and adapted to my project.

```
graph=path+'/profile.txt'
x, y = loadtxt(graph, unpack=True)
x = x*1000
y = y*1000
ax.plot(x,y)

x0 = 1.0
i0 = np.argmin(np.abs(x-x0))
x1 = x[i0:i0+2]
y1 = y[i0:i0+2]
dydx, = np.diff(y1)/np.diff(x1)
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
tngnt = lambda x: dydx*x + (y1[0]-dydx*x1[0])

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x1[0],y1[0], "or")
plt.plot(x,tngnt(x), label="tangent")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

However I get an error
`script.py:43: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divid  dydx, = np.diff(y1)/np.diff(x1)`

[image]

I get the point I am interested where I want to get the tangent but I am having difficulty with the division to get the tangent line. I have tried `tck = interpolate.splrep(x,y)` but got nothing besides the original profile.

I am new to Python and any guidance is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

My new code to get rid of repeated x values

**dataframe to list**

```
df = pd.read_csv('asc_conejetprofile1.csv',skipinitialspace = False,delim_whitespace=True)
#print(df)
df.columns = ['x','y']
#print(df)

result_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x', 'y'], keep='first')
#print(result_df)
#plot(df['x'],df['y'])

np.savetxt(r'sorted.txt',result_df, delimiter=' ',fmt='%5.12f')


graph='sorted.txt'
x, y = loadtxt(graph, unpack=True) 
#print(x)
x = x*1000
y = y*1000

x0 = 1.0
i0 = np.argmin(np.abs(x-x0))
x1 = x[i0:i0+2]
y1 = y[i0:i0+2]
dydx, = np.diff(y1)/np.diff(x1)

tngnt = lambda x: dydx*x + (y1[0]-dydx*x1[0])

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x1[0],y1[0], "or")
plt.plot(x,tngnt(x), label="tangent")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your `x1` array contains duplicated values, so `np.diff(x1)` returns `0` for the differences between these duplicated values. Dividing by `0` gives the `RuntimeWarning` (and `inf` or `nan` in the resulting array). You should filter the indices where the difference between adjacent values is zero before calculating the ratio.

Comment: That makes sense! I have managed to get rid of repeated values using dataframe (I have edited my question and added my code there). However, if I replace the previously used ```x``` with ```df['x']```, I am getting an error  ```tngnt = lambda df['x']: dydx*df['x'] + (y1[0]-dydx*x1[0])
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: You cannot use `df['x']` as input argument for a lambda function, you should leave it as it was in the original function and use `tngnt(df['x'])` in the `plt.plot` call.

Comment: I tried different way and finally got tangent line. Many thanks @luuk. Can I ask how should I compute the tangent line cutting x -axis?

Comment: I have tried this ```idx = (tngnt(x)>-0.001)*(tngnt(x)<0.001) print(np.where(idx)) print(x[np.where(idx)])``` and I am getting a result. Do you think this is an appropriate way?