# Finding arrays of pixels perpendicular to a derivative

Tags: python, image-processing, linear-algebra, opencv, calculus

I am developing a method for “straightening” binary-masks of pictures of carrot roots.  I have traced midlines through the masks.  For example, I start with a binary mask:

[image: binary mask]

I then use Voronoi diagrams to estimate the midline, as shown in red:

[image: binary mask + midline]

I would now like to find the length of the “slices” that run perpendicular to the midline at each point, which would then constitute the appropriate width of the root at any given point along its length.  I am using a method similar to that explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391449/find-tangent-vector-at-a-point-for-discrete-data-points) to find the derivative of the fitted spline connecting points along the midline:

```
def get_spline_derivative(points):

x_max = points[:, 0].max()
# x_min = points[:, 0].min()
new_length = x_max

x = points[:, 0]
y = points[:, 1]

# new_x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, new_length)

# new_x = np.linspace(0, 1, 2000)  # this is the one that works
new_x = np.linspace(0, 1, new_length)  # this is the one that works

tck, u = itp.splprep([x, y])
dx, dy = itp.splev(new_x, tck, der=1)

return list(zip(dx, dy))
```

This produces an enormous array, shortened here (full output [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwzmo7syetfciqu/spline-derivative.txt?dl=0)):

```
[(-559.8864500362733, -105.4032498463578), (-560.2848158832071, -109.774387868758), (-560.6711489905051, -113.82253391400316), (-561.0454493581669, -117.54768798209324), (-561.4077169861929, -120.94985007302827), ... (-533.1106034956821, 74.87936144117594)]
```

I am unsure how to then use this output to find the vector perpendicular to this derivative, and then calculate the length of the “bin” of pixels that is within the polygon, running along this vector.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: This is more of a mathematical problem, so you could try https://math.stackexchange.com if nobody responds here.

Comment: You can calculate aproximate derivatives using `np.gradient(arr)[0]` (0 for (x,y) pair values), and corresponding perpendicular vectors using `np.gradient(x)[0][:,::-1]*[-1,1]`. Not sure about pixel bins calculation though.